# Android ICS Options menu with images

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android.

How can i create option menu with out images like in the attached image? Do i need to use action bar or normal `onCreateOptionMenu` will do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> If you've developed your application for Android 3.0 (API level 11)
>   and higher, items from the options menu are available in the action
>   bar. By default, the system places all items in the action overflow,
>   which the user can reveal with the action overflow icon on the right
>   side of the action bar (or by pressing the device Menu button, if
>   available). To enable quick access to important actions, you can
>   promote a few items to appear in the action bar by adding
>   android:showAsAction="ifRoom" to the corresponding  elements.

You can refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) for more detail.

Comment: only if there is space menu will be added to actionbar else it will be shown on click of menu button, at that time, how one can customize it? that is what he has asked